# Why are my ginger falling over and drooping?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, irrigation, ginger

They started drooping during winter while it was raining and the soil if anything was too muddy. Now that it's drying up a bit I've turned the irrigation on for 30 minutes every 48 hrs. The soil is nice and damp at the root zone. There are healthy new shoots coming now also. Just planted all of these late last autumn. Totaling 8 5 gallon plants.